# 'dlantr' at (1) is not a function

Tags: fortran, gfortran, lapack

I'm facing an odd problem while trying to use Lapack function `dlantr` to compute norm of triangular matrix. Basically, I had a working single-file program with `dlantr` and some other Lapack procedures in it, and now I want to split it into modules. `dlantr` ended in subroutine in one such module. However, trying to compile said module with gfortran-10 (through MPI wrapper compiler, since there's also some MPI in there) like

```
mpifort -o kde.o -c kde.f90
```

leads to an error :

```
‘dlantr’ at (1) is not a function
```

which is strange, because

- other Lapack procedures (in my case `dtrtri` and `dpotrf`) in the same subroutine work alright
- a simple subroutine in a same module like

```
subroutine foo(a)
    real(kind=DP), intent(in) :: a(2,2)
    real(kind=DP) :: tmp, dlantr
    print*, dlantr('F','L','N',2,2,a,2,tmp)**2
end subroutine
```

also works fine when called from the main program. In the subroutine where the problem arises, it is declared in the same way as above and in the original program, that is
`real(kind=DP) :: ..., dlantr, ...`

The code in question can be found [here](https://github.com/PYunker/ProbAmpSampling/blob/master/kde/mse/kde.f90). What could be causing such behaviour, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original answer was wrong. This is a compiler bug, probably https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87127. Still, this workaround of explicitly using the `external` attribute makes the error go away:

```
    real(kind=DP), external :: dlantr
```

The MWE for this bug is:

```
subroutine sub
    integer :: d
    real :: f
    real :: a
    
    associate (c => d)
        a = f()
    end associate
end subroutine sub
```

Comment: "You cannot declare a variable and a function return type at the same line" - really?

Comment: @francescalus Maybe yes, because it works in the simple sample. but in the full code it did make the error go away. Confused...

Comment: @francescalus Maybe it is actually some compiler bug. It goes away when making a MCVE.

Comment: Ifort compiles it ok.

Comment: If it's a restriction of the language then it's a particularly well hidden one.  There certainly are times where EXTERNAL Is required to be explicitly stated (and such a case would require either an `external` statement or attribute on a separate declaration line), but without looking at the code I can't say whether that's the case here.